Simulation of quasi-static fluids
I'm doing a school project asking to investigate the wirtz pump (a thin tube coiled to a vertical spiral shape, a part of which underwater, and the pump turns, water enters the spiral and move towards the center, which is connected to a tube stretching upwards). A want to simulate it with a software. As the pump turns slowly, it can be seen as a quasi-static process, neglecting the internal flows of water, only focusing on the pressure of water and air. I wonder if any software is appropriate to simulate quasi-static fluids? Thanks

static fluids are easy, it's moving fluids that present problems.  A static fluid will have a height equal to the pressure at the bottom.

@TigerGuy yes, but it is still too complicated to calculate by hand if there are too many parts of water and too many restraints which are not linear. So I still wants to find an easier way to simulate the system, or do I have to write a code from scratch?

I don't understand what is hard about static liquids.  All the liquid will have the same water column height
